# Arbitrary type conversion in python

Tags: python, casting

An arbitrary typecasting function (shown below as `cast`) seems like a fairly straightforward function:

```
print(type(variable))
variable = cast(variable,type) # where type is any type included in __builtins__
print(type(variable))
```

And the result:

```
>>> <original_type>
>>> <type>
```

Does such a function exist in python? I can't seem to find any reference to it if it does. If this function does not exist, please explain the rationale for why it does not.

As one example usage, I have a config with arbitrarily many values, and a schema with the desired type of each. I want to check that specified value for each config variable can be cast as corresponding type specified in the schema. Treating each as a dict below for convenience:

```
for variable in config.keys():
    val = config[variable]
    type_name = schema[variable]
   
    try:
       config[variable] = cast(val,type_name)
    except TypeError:
       print("Schema checking failed for variable {}".format(variable))
```

Comment: No, it is impossible. You cannot change the value held by `variable` by passing it into a function.

Comment: No. Many constructors of builtin objects like "str", "int", "float" can take objects of some other types and return a new converted object.

Comment: Are you refering to the [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) function? That does nothing at runtime. It's for static type checkers. Usually you just use the type as a function. eg. `str(123)`, or `int('123')`.

Comment: Assuming you *can* create a value of the new type, it would just be `cast = lambda v, type: type(v)`. Python is strongly typed, though; it doesn't have casting in the sense you might be thinking of from a language like C, where type casting simply changes how the compiler views the bits in a variable.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make much sense. As noted in the comments, you cannot change the type of an object in-place (well, you *can* for user-defined types with no `__slots__`, but you really *shouldn't*)

Comment: Ok, the in-place nature of the function was not the relevant part of my question. Changed to reflect this

Comment: @DerekG still it isn't clear what you are talking about. It really isn't possible to convert one type of object to another type of object in general. So I see no reason why you think this *should* or *could* exist. How should `cast(14, set)` work, for example? Or `cast(3.14149, MyClass)` work?

Comment: Also, the word "cast", while commonly used to just mean "type conversion" can be a bit ambiguous. depending on the language/context,  it can mean either the re-interpretation of a bit-pattern or a real data representation conversion. i.e. "casting" `3.14159` could mean converting to `3` or to `4614256650576692846`. In `numpy`, this is the difference between `np.array(3.14159).astype(int)` vs `np.array(3.14159).view(int)`

Comment: in the example above, you could just do `type_name(val)` assuming `type_name` is an actual type, not a string with the name of the type.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok yeah that seems right. What's best protocol here, just delete my question?

Comment: Up to you. I mean, you could also answer it yourself (and even accept your answer). I think there is a downvoted answer here already that pretty much says the same thing!

Comment: And just to elaborate a bit, types in Python *are objects themselves*. A class is a type, i.e. `int` is a *class object*, itself an *instance of `type`* (which is a metaclass, a class that creates classes!). Indeed, you can create a class using `MyClass = type("MyClass", (Parent,), {"some_method": lambda self: print("Hi from", self)})` then `my_instance = MyClass(); my_instance.some_method()`

Comment: @DerekG the thing to understand is there is *really no fundamental difference*. A function can just as easily implement a type conversion. contructors themselves are *just functions*. `SomeType(x)` just calls the constructor, and that is the protocol we follow. Indeed, the "logic" of object construction *is in fact* implemented in `type.__call__`, so that instances of `type`, e.g. `int` are *callable*, `int(x)`!. Generally speaking, `type.__call__` just does `instance. = object.__new__(cls); if isinstance(instance, cls): instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs); return instance`

Comment: For the curious, here is the actual implementation of `type.__call__`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8cf2906828b4ea281ea5381bf59b9052bae99f53/Objects/typeobject.c#L1064

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the comments have covered the matter in enough detail so I'll just try to summarize my best understanding of them here. Most of this is by way of @juanpa.arrivillaga.

A standard python *casting* operation like `int(x)` (or more precisely, a type conversion operation), is actually a call to the `__call__()` function of an object. Types like `int`, `float`, `str`, etc are all object classes and are all instances of the metaclass `type`. A call to one of these instance of `type` e.g. `int.__call__()`  calls the `int` object constructor which creates a new instance of that type and initializes it with the inputs to `__call__()`.

In short, there is nothing special or different about the common python "type conversions" (e.g. `int(x)`, `str(40)`) other than that the `int` and `str` objects are included in `__builtins__`.

And to answer the original question, if `type_name` is an instance of the `type` class then the `type_name.__call__()` function simply declares and initializes a new instance of that type. Thus, one can simply do:

```
# convert x to type type_name
x = type_name(x)
```

however this may cause an exception if `x` is not a valid input to the  `type_name` constructor.

Answer (score -1):

To *cast* a value in another type you can use the type itself, you can pass the type as an argument and call it into a function and you can get it from the `builtins` module if you sure that the type is a builtin:

```py
value = "1"
value = int(value) # set value to 1

value = 1
value = str(value) # set value to "1"

def cast(value, type_):
    return type_(value)

import buitlins
def builtin_cast(value, type_):
    type_ = getattr(buitlins, type_, None)
    if isinstance(type_, type):
        return type_(value)
    raise ValueError(f"{type_!r} is not a builtins type.")

value = cast("1", int) # set value to 1
value = cast(1, str) # set value to "1"

value = builtin_cast("1", "int") # set value to 1
value = builtin_cast(1, "str") # set value to "1"
```

Comment: Not in general, no.